# Initilising a class in void setup and using it in void loop - Arduino - ESP32 - c++ -visual studio code

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-code, arduino, esp32

I'm trying to keep some good habbits by creating a class when needed, but i'm also trying to teach myself some robotics.

I'm practicing on an esp32 in visual studio and i've written a class to easily convert a sensors value (an LDR) to an outputs value (in this case a servo).

I realise this is pretty convoluted for a simple input output but i could imagine something like this being useful in much bigger projects...that being said if this is really not the way to do things, please let me know.

anyway, im trying to initialise my class object in `void seup(){}` and use its functions etc in `void loop{}` but visual studio is throwing a "identifier "ldr_servo1" is undefinedC/C++(20)" (see below)

I've tried some reference/pointer things but to no success. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks is advance!

**here's the header file**

```
class ldr_to_servo
{
private:
    
    int ldr_pin;
    int servo_pin;
    int ldr_max;
    int servo_max;
    int ldr_min;
    int servo_min;
    int servo_position = 0;
    //servo setup
    Servo servo1;

public:


    ldr_to_servo(int new_ldr_pin, int new_servo_pin, int new_ldr_max, int new_servo_max,int new_ldr_min, int new_servo_min);
    ~ldr_to_servo();

    int get_ldr_value();
    int ldr_val_to_servo_val(int current_ldr_value);
    int write_servo_value(int converted_ldr_value);
```

***here's the class cpp file***

```
#include "ldr_to_servo.hpp"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <ESP32Servo.h>


ldr_to_servo::ldr_to_servo(int new_ldr_pin, int new_servo_pin, int new_ldr_max, int new_servo_max,int new_ldr_min, int new_servo_min){
   ldr_pin = new_ldr_pin;
   servo_pin = new_servo_pin;
   ldr_max = new_ldr_max;
   servo_max = new_servo_max;
   ldr_min = new_ldr_min;
   servo_min = new_servo_min;
   //LDR setup
   pinMode(ldr_pin, INPUT);
   //servo setup
   ESP32PWM::allocateTimer(0);
   ESP32PWM::allocateTimer(1);
   ESP32PWM::allocateTimer(2);
   ESP32PWM::allocateTimer(3);
   servo1.setPeriodHertz(50);    
   servo1.attach(servo_pin, 1000, 2000); 

}

ldr_to_servo::~ldr_to_servo(){

}

int ldr_to_servo::get_ldr_value(){
    analogRead(ldr_pin);

}

int ldr_to_servo::ldr_val_to_servo_val(int ldr_value){

    int new_value;
    new_value = map(ldr_value,ldr_min,ldr_max,servo_min,servo_max);
    return new_value;
     
     

}

int ldr_to_servo::write_servo_value(int converted_ldr_value){
    servo1.write(converted_ldr_value);
}
```

***and heres the main.cpp file***

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>
#include "ldr_to_servo.hpp"


#define onboard_led 2 // stores value before being compiles (saves mems)
#define ldr_pin 4 // photo resistor
#define servo_pin 36 //servo pin
#define analog_max 4095 //max reading of analog pin
#define analog_min 0
#define servo_max_degrees 180
#define servo_min_degrees 0



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ldr_to_servo ldr_servo1(ldr_pin, servo_pin, analog_max, servo_max_degrees, analog_min, servo_min_degrees);




}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int ldr_value =  ldr_servo1.get_ldr_value();

}
```

my problem is with this very last line - VS codes throws a **"identifier "ldr_servo1" is undefinedC/C++(20)"** error

Thanks again in advance!!

Comment: Variables defined in one function can't be used in another function, as any decent C++ book should have taught you. You need to think of another way and place to create your variable to make it available for both functions.

Comment: thanks for the scathing burn haha, ive just called the class outside of the void setup. will see if it works, will probably need to change some stuff in the class!

Comment: that is why they use `begin()` in other hardware wrapping classes

Answer (score 0):

You are using .hpp instead of .cpp

Comment: You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.